# How to swap Ctrl and Function key?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, keybindings

I'm trying to swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> on Catalina without downloading a new app. As suggested in multiple articles, I tried going to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **keyboard** > **Modifier Keys..** in hopes to simply swap the function of two keys. However, <kbd>Fn</kbd> is missing from the list of modifier keys. Am I missing something here? Do I need to do something else to make <kbd>Fn</kbd> key show up there?

EDIT: I'm using Macbook Pro with touch bar.

Comment: What keyboard do you have. I see 5 keys on the modifier dialog. (albeit Mojave) including function key, but function only appears on the function key's set of choices.

Comment: If we don't get an answer re Apple software you can use the third party free Karabiner https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Comment: I've a keyboard with a touch bar (now updated in the question). I was trying to avoid using Karabiner, but I don't think I'm out of choices. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

From Apple documentation ([Change the behaviour of the modifier keys on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchlp1011/mac))

> On macOS 10.13 and later, you can also change the behaviour of the
> Function key on keyboards that have an Fn key – except keyboards with
> a Touch Bar.

Comment: Yes but you can't change any other key to the function key

Comment: I think this is what I missed. I do have a keyboard with a touch bar. That explains why I don't see the Fn key there. Thanks a ton!